# How do I insert an Edit widget in ArcGIS Experience?

Tags: editing, widget, arcgis-experience-builder

I've been desperately looking for the Edit Widget in ArcGIS Experience. I read the documentation, I have the Map Widget ready, but there is just no Edit Widget among the list of Widgets in the Add Widgets section. I feel pretty stupid because it should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using enterprise or online? It is only available from v. 11 of enterprise.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/experience-builder/11.0/configure-widgets/edit-widget.htm